# Port 80 mixed up among clients using DNAT

Tags: routes, virtualization, nat, netfilter, dmz

I'm trying to set up a network like this:

[image: Network map]

...but I'm facing an issue.

Here's the point:

**If I try to reach (e.g.) *mywebsite1.com* from external it works like a charm and it's shown my wonderful website but whenever I try to run (e.g.) *apt-get update* from inside the Virtual Server 2 it throws an error like "*Failed to connect to xxx-whatever-website.com port 80: connection refused*".**

The problem is solved if I delete the prerouting rule on the main server firewall but, of course, then I'm not more able to connect to *mywebsite1.com* from external. Same story if I change the Virtual Server default gateway to 192.168.1.1.

I naively tried to add a static route on the main server (something like ip route add 192.168.1.1 via 192.168.1.32) but, of course, it didn't work. Should I try to mark the packets in some way or something, in order to recognize the source client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I omitted the original destination target in my DNAT rule, it hit all original destination targets. So, I needed to add `-d 192.168.1.30` to it.

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i vmbr0 -d 192.168.1.30 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.32:80
```

Now it works.